# MySQL tables are not UTF-8 even though I instructed Hibernate to do create them with UTF-8

Tags: mysql, hibernate, utf-8, spring-boot

I'm using a Spring Boot application and even though I instructed Hibernate to make new tables in `UTF-8`, all new tables are in `latin1`.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
```

I'm using Hikari.

Comment: I think you must do this setting in database level

Comment: I'm looking into it. But cant find a definite answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My DB had latin1 encoding:

```
SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;
```

Fix the DB first:

```
foreach table: ALTER TABLE @table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER DATABASE javabg CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

make sure all connections are in utf8 - edit my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]
#mist: set default encoding to utf-8
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: No.  Don't do that `CONVERT TO` unless you are sure you have the problem for which that is the solution.  Else, you could make the problem worse.

Comment: I fixed them, what do you mean worse? If I go from utf8 to latin1, probably yes, but from latin1 to utf8?

Comment: If you had utf8 blindly crammed into latin1 (without proper conversion), then the CONVERT TO would do a second conversion, making it harder to recover the 'correct' text.  See "Case 1" in [my blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#conversions_and_common_errors).

Comment: I don't think you can revert `?????` to the actual string. I used th mysql `HEX` function from the other answer and it yields `3F3F3F3F`. Maybe before the conversion there might have been a chance, but I thought the data was lost on `insert`. Now, after, the convert - no chance.

Answer (score 0):

Caution:  `init-connect` is ignored when you connect as `root`.

`ALTER TABLE @table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;` applies only if you have proper latin1 encodings of data in the table now.  If you have put non-Western-European text in latin1 fields, the solution is other.  Please do

```
SELECT col, HEX(col) ...
```

to see what is in there now.

If the output is to be on a web page, you need to check that the meta tag specifies utf8.